# How to redirect a nested resource in routes.rb in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

I want to redirect *http://mysite.com/docs/some-old-link* to *http://mysite.com/docs/some-new-link* (some-old-link is gone). Here's what I'm trying:

```
resources :docs, :only => [:index, :show] do
  member do
    match "some-old-link"   => redirect("some-new-link")
  end
end
```

But the redirect isn't happening and I just get 404 on some-old-link. Tried various tweaks on this but can't get it. How do I do this?

Comment: have you tried printing to console right above the `member do`, and then right above the `match "some-old-link"   => redirect("some-new-link")`, to make sure it's getting called?

Comment: How about match "docs/some-old-link" => redirect("docs/some-new-link")

Comment: @Max OK just tried that, and both get printed during rails startup, not when the request is made (I'm guessing routes.rb gets run only once at startup to initialize the routes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try to add "to" to your code:

```
match "some-old-link",  to: redirect("some-new-link")
```

The problem also could be:

```
 member do
    match "some-old-link"   => redirect("some-new-link")
  end
```

Is expected to redirect sth like this:

*/docs/**id**/some-old-link* to */docs/**id**/some-new-link*

try using *collection* instead of *member*

Comment: Thanks! Used collection instead of member -- this gives me the error: `ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: localhost:3000some-new-link`. However `redirect("/docs/some-new-link")` does the trick.